# Regular expression to extract numbers within repeated underscores

Tags: regex

I have strings that look like this:

```
nominal_0_297_e3GsQ4dawR6n9ETDj
```

I would like a regular expression to extract `0_297` and both numbers (i.e., 0 and 297 in this case) can go between 0 and 1000.

I tried:

```
(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\_)
```

But this extracts `0` and not `0_297`

Comment: Your current regex match `0_297`. You need `0` and `297` as two different match ?

Comment: @CodeManiac this `(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\_)` currently extracts `0` and not `0_297`

Comment: @amaatouq it does extract `0_297`, [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/kj1QiH/1/)

Comment: @amaatouq make sure you're using `global` flag, else it will match just the first occurrence of pattern

Comment: @CodeManiac Interesting! when I use pandas (python library) with `df.index.astype(str).str.extract("(?<=\_)(.*?)(?=\_)", expand=True)` I get only `0` without the rest! I wonder how str.extract works then!

Comment: `_((\d+)_(\d+))_` will capture `0_297` into `$1`, `0` into `$2`, and `297` into `$3`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus this works!

Comment: `str.extract` extracts the first match, `str.extractall` / `str.findall` extracts all matches. Use `df.index.astype(str).str.findall(r'(?<=_)\d+(?=_)')`, or `df.index.astype(str).str.extractall(r'(?<=_)(\d+)(?=_)', expand=True)`. Always indicate where you are using the regex and share the relevant code as regex is always library-dependent.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
_((\d+)_(\d+))_
```

and it will capture `0_297` into `$1`, `0` into `$2`, and `297` into `$3`

https://regex101.com/r/nR3qTZ/1